# MISRA-C rule 10.5

Tags: c++, c, linux, misra

I have the following static analysis report that the code is not compliant for MISRA-C rule 10.5 :

> Results of ~ and << operations on operands of underlying types
> unsigned char and unsigned short should immediately be cast to the
> operand's underlying type

The code is :

```
unsigned val = ~0U;
```

From what i understand, the idea is to have to maximum value of an `unsigned int` which can also be achieved by `unsigned val = UINT_MAX;` from `<limits.h>`.

However, i would like to know if there is something wrong with this code.

To me, `0U` is of type unsigned integer and has a value of `0`, then operator `~` is applied which gives a result of type `unsigned int` with all bits set to `1` and finally it is copied to an `unsigned int`.

I would say that no integer promotion happens here before the operator `~` because we already have an `unsigned int`.

Moreover, the tool gives the same report somewhere else in the code :

```
uint16_t val2 = (uint16_t)(~0U); /* cast is explicit so what is wrong here ? */
```

I am not sure whether or not this code needs a fix for both "offending" lines.

Comment: Would you mind choosing between C and C++? You're more likely to get answers from a more targeted question.

Comment: Yes, this is C++ code compiled with GCC on 64 bits architecture (CentOS)

Comment: Which MISRA? MISRA-C++:2008?

Comment: MISRA-C++ 2008 and MISRA-C 2004 are referenced by the tool.

Comment: Feel free to name & shame your static analyser btw, in case someone looking to buy one comes across this thread. If I had a dollar for every "your MISRA checker is broken" answer I've posted here...

Comment: Curious as to why you are using MISRA.  Are you writing automobile code for embedded systems?

Comment: @Eljay You might want to have a peek at [Is MISRA-C useful outside safety-critical and embedded programming?](https://software.codidact.com/q/279077).

Comment: @Eljay the code is not for automotive embedded systems

Comment: Then why are you trying to make MISRA compliant code?  I've looked into the applicable of MISRA to some of my projects, and found my projects to be outside the domain of MISRA.  MISRA is awesome, in context.  Outside of that context, it's moot.

Comment: @Eljay - nothing in MISRA limits it to automotive...

Comment: @Lundin - I note (in your referenced link) the flawed Kernel recommendation NOT to brace single statements in if/while etc.  Surely, after Apple's SSL fiasco, that argument has been lost?

Comment: @Andrew You seem to be assuming that Linux development is driven by some sort of rationale... it is as if the project takes pride in the fact that it's one of the most horrible code bases ever written in C. I used to be a fan of Linux until I started reading the kernel code and libs.

Comment: @Lundin - agreed... Linux has some laudable aims, but is corrupted by the pseudo-religion that its devotees subscribe to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept *underlying type* was used in the older MISRAs, nowadays deprecated and replaced with essential type categories. The definition of underlying type is the type that each of the operands in an expression would have if not for implicit type promotion.

In the expression `~0U`, the type of the integer constant `0U` is `unsigned int`. It is not a small integer type, so no integer promotion takes place upon `~`. The underlying type is the same as the actual C language type, `unsigned int`.

`unsigned val = ...` assigns an `unsigned int` to an `unsigned int`. No lvalue conversion through assignment or other such implicit assignment takes place. The underlying type remains `unsigned int`.

Thus if your tool gives a warning about no cast to underlying type on the line `unsigned val = ~0U;`, your tool is simply broken.

---

> From what i understand, the idea is to have to maximum value of an unsigned int

Very likely.

> However, i would like to know if there is something wrong with this code.

No, nothing is wrong with your code. However, other MISRA rules require you to replace the default "primitive types" with types from `stdint.h` (or equivalent on pre-C99 compilers). So in case this is a 32 bit system, the MISRA compliant version of your code is `uint32_t val`.

> `uint16_t val2 = (uint16_t)(~0U);`

This is MISRA compliant code. The underlying type of the assignment expression is `uint16_t`. Casting to `uint16_t` is correct and proper practice. Again, your tool is broken.